# errors FS0001 or FS0041 while attempting to retrieve nunit test attributes from an assembly

Tags: f#, nunit

the F# script below fails with FS0041 (A unique overload for method 'GetCustomAttributes' could not be determined based on type information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed) . How do you fix it?

If I add type annotations such as

```
let getattr (el : Sometype) = Attribute.CustomAttributes(el, true)
```

it fails with FS0001 (The type 'Sometype' is not compatible with the type 'Assembly'.
Possible overload: ...long lines omitted...)

```
open System
open System.Reflection

let nunit_tattr = typeof<NUnit.Framework.TestFixtureAttribute>
let getattr el = Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(el, true)
let _ =
    let asm = Assembly.LoadFile("some_asm_that_contains_nunit_tests.dll")
    let ttypes = asm.GetTypes()
    let allattrs = Seq.map getattr ttypes
    printf "%A\n" allattrs
```

On the other hand in the REPL I get a little bit further.

```
    > let z  = ttypes.[0];;

    val z : Type = Foo.Bar.Cow.Test.AaaTest

    > Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(z, true);;
    val it : Attribute [] =
    [|NUnit.Framework.TestFixtureAttribute
        {Arguments = [||];
         Categories = null;
         Category = null;
         Description = null;
         Ignore = false;
         IgnoreReason = null;
         TypeArgs = [||];
         TypeId = NUnit.Framework.TestFixtureAttribute;}|]
```

The purpose of this exercise is to filter out methods that do not have NUnit.Framework.TestFixtureAttribute (that code is not shown).
The array elements in ttypes are heterogeneous, for example index 0 shown above
has type Foo.Bar.Cow.Test.AaaTest but index 1 has type Foo.Bar.Cow.Test.BbbTest, etc.

Start fsharpi like so

```
    fsharpi /r:/usr/lib/cli/nunit.framework-2.6/nunit.framework.dll
```

Comment: Actual error messages would be more useful than just the error codes.

Comment: ok, added a little bit more detail

Comment: ttypes is not heterogeneous, it's an array of Types (as in, elements of type Type).

Comment: also, do you want to look for Tests or TestFixtures? You seem to confuse them in your question...

Comment: TestFixtures, just fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to read up on reflection and what the `Type` type actually stands for.

To get you started - if you want to get the types that have a specific attribute, check this script:

```
open System
open System.Reflection

/// an attribute and some types to test it on
type ExampleAttribute () = 
   inherit Attribute ()

[<Example>] type A = A
type B = B    
[<Example>] type C = C

/// get the types in an assembly
let types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()

/// filter the types that are marked with ExampleAttribute (gives you A and C)
types 
|> Array.filter (fun typ -> typ.IsDefined(typeof<ExampleAttribute>))
```

Note the `typeof` operator - it's the way to go from a static type name (the ExampleAttribute string in the code) to an object of type `Type`, which is the runtime representation of ExampleAttribute type.

Comment: thanks man, it worked. Can you explain why the pipeline syntax gets rid of error FS0072, in other words "Array.filter (fun typ -> typ.IsDefined(typeof<ExampleAttribute>)) types" doesn't work

Comment: @snik197: that's a consequence of how type inference works in F#. With the pipeline it already knows the type of `types` before it gets to the filter. That's a useful trick, but all it saves you is writing the annotation - `Array.filter (fun (typ: Type) -> ...) types` would work just as well.